# SSIS 2012: Package fails from SQL Agent but runs OK manually

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-agent

There is a Master package as below to call and run all child packages in my SSIS solution by Project Reference. Also, all connection managers are set at project level since all packages are sharing the same ones.

[image]

When manually running, everything works well from master to last child. However, when the master package is executed from a SQL Agent, it shows error as follows:

```
Code: 0xC001000E     Source: Master      
Description: The connection "{5A827D76-916C-4F22-ADE9-266ABBEB1E37}" is not found. 
This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found.
```

Then I checked the connection ID and found it is an OLE DB connection manager in the first child package as follows:
[image]

I'm not sure if I should replace project connections with package level to fix this issue. Hopefully someone could help me out. Thanks in advance!

Some more info that might be helpful:

1. All connection managers are connect to SQL-Server 2012 and my visual studio version is 2010.
2. An SSIS proxy is created with the same windows account of packages for SQL Agent to execute. It also has full control to all DBs used in solution.
3. SQL Agent is set as below:
   [image]

Comment: What is that connection manager connected to? I bet dollars to dumplings it's a file based entity (Excel or Flat File) and the SQL Agent account or the Credentials which power the job step task of SSIS do not have access to the location. Can you verify?

Comment: Actually it's an OLE DB connection manager. Sorry I forgot to mention in question...

Comment: Sorry, Bill: hand over the dumplings.

Comment: OLE DB Connection manager to what? And it seems I'll be providing dumplings in the near future

Comment: OLE DB Connection to a Sql server 2012 database.

Comment: @billinkc    More info has been added to question for your reference  :-)

Comment: Project level connection managers should be fine. In fact, they're far less hassle IMO than per package so no need to swap them out. Is the failing connection manager used in the Master package? When you run it manually and it works fine and when it runs from Agent and fails, are they both pointing to the same servers? Are there explicit configurations applied in the SSISDB?

Comment: @billinkc  The packages are not deployed to SSISDB but saved in file system. Also, package files and DBs are at same server. SQL Agent only calls master package to run. Then I got the error msg once task started.

Comment: When you say it's project reference and based on your other question, you *are* using the project deployment model and not the package model? You *can* run packages in a .ispac but that's some trouble... Maybe I'm not understanding your approach. Could you post the Execute Package task details. Also, cheers from just over the border ;)

Comment: @billinkc Yes I know it's confusing. Please ignore the other question first... That one occurs when I tried to fix this problem by deploying all packages to SSISDB. I will post more detailed snapshots. Haha, i love country club plaza!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38366/discussion-between-echo-and-billinkc)